# Integrate in terms of t

Tags: calculus

Find the value of:

$$\int _{ 0 }^{ 1 }{ \frac { x^{ t }-1 }{ \ln { x }  } { dx } } $$

in terms of $t$, given that the integral converges.

I don't know where to start.

Answer (score 5):

Using [Leibniz rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign) gives

$$
\dfrac{\partial}{\partial t}\int\limits^{1}_{0}\dfrac{x^t-1}{\log x}\,\mathrm{d}x{}={}\int\limits^{1}_{0}\dfrac{\partial}{\partial t}\left(\dfrac{x^t-1}{\log x}\right)\,\mathrm{d}x{}={}\int\limits^{1}_{0}x^t\,\mathrm{d}x{}={}\dfrac{1}{t+1}\,.
$$

Therefore, the desired result is given by integration w.r.t. variable $t$.

> $$
> \int \dfrac{1}{t+1}\,\mathrm d t{}={}\log\left(t+1\right)\,.
> $$

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, note that $$\int_0^t \ln(x)\cdot x^y\space dy=x^t-1$$
Therefore:
$$
\int_0^1 \frac{x^t-1}{\ln(x)}\space dx=\int_0^1 \frac{\int_0^t \ln(x)\cdot x^y\space dy}{\ln(x)}\space dx=\int_0^1 \int_0^t x^y\space dy\space dx=\int_0^t \int_0^1 x^y\space dx\space dy=\int_0^t \frac{1}{y+1}\space dy=\ln(1+t)
$$